# SQL Server Installation for a Distributed Availability Group

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, distributed-availability-groups

I am deploying a SQL Server 2019 Distributed Availability Group. I have created a WSFC at each of my two sites (spanning two servers each). Upon installing SQL Server, it is not clear to me if I should select the "SQL Server Stand-Alone" installation or the "SQL Server Cluster Installation"? I do not wish to deploy a SQL Server Failover Cluster Instance (FCI).

Thank you. J.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will select "SQL Server Stand-Alone" installation.

To create a distributed availability group, you must create two availability groups each with its own listener. You then combine these availability groups into a distributed availability group.

Once you do that on all nodes you can use these instructions to configure the Always On distributed availability group.

[Configure an Always On distributed availability group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/configure-distributed-availability-groups?view=sql-server-ver15&tabs=automatic)

Comment: Thank you @SqlWorldWide